# How to re-run this jQuery plugin on window resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list where the first-child element is visible on desktop, and is hidden on screens under 767px, and then every other element cycles through on a loop for all screen sizes.

I have been trying to re-run this jQuery plugin on window resize without success, please could someone help implement window resize function?

I have put together an [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/yodihew/qgz8dfLj/6/)

```
(function ($){
$.fn.extend({ 
    rotaterator: function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        pauseSpeed: 100,
        child:null
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        var o =options;
        var obj = $(this);          
        var obj2 = "ul li:first-child";                   
        var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
        var items2 = $(obj.children(), obj2);

        if ($(window).width() < 767) {
            items.each(function() {$(this).hide();})
            items2.each(function() {$(obj2).hide();})
        } else {
            items.each(function() {$(this).hide();})
            items2.each(function() {$(obj2).show();})
        }
        if(!o.child){var next = $(obj).children(':nth-child(2)');

        }else{var next = o.child;

        }
        $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
            $(next).delay(o.pauseSpeed).fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function() {
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (next.length == 0){
                    next = $(obj).children(':nth-child(2)');
                }
                $(obj).rotaterator({child : next, fadeSpeed : o.fadeSpeed, pauseSpeed : o.pauseSpeed});
            })
        });
    });

}
});
})(jQuery);
```

and call

```
(function ($) {
        $('ul').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:5000, pauseSpeed:1000});
        })(jQuery);
```

Thanks for looking.

UPDATE:

I have added window resize, it seems it's had an affect of how it initially loads and performs thereafter, showing all elements first, please see [updated fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yodihew/qgz8dfLj/14/)

Comment: *"a better way"*: so you have a way. In that case your question is off-topic for StackOverflow (maybe it is suitable for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)). If you have a problem with your way, you should  describe the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear/specific, I did put together the solution, it works, but I'm struggling to get the window re-size function implemented, also my question for better ways to achieve was to see if people could simplify the solution, but in turn it just over-complicated my question. Thanks for responding. (I have updated my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation already adapts to the new window size as soon as the fade-out completes and the next call to `rotaterator` is made.

If however you want an immediate effect at the resize event, so that the animation restarts taking the new window size into account, then use the jQuery `stop` method to stop any current animations of an `ul` child element.

For instance:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('ul *').finish();
    $('ul').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:5000, pauseSpeed:1000});
});
```

Comment: Thank you Trincot, that's helped a lot I appreciate it, I did want an immediate effect at the resize event, also immediate effect on first load, so I added .trigger which appears to work how I'd like it. Thanks again.

`$(window).on('resize',function() {
   $('ul *').finish();
   $('ul').rotaterator({fadeSpeed:5000, pauseSpeed:500});
}).trigger('resize');`